# How to exclude a variable from a test in gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to calculate the SMD for all variables except for one.

For example I would like the following table to show no value in column "Difference" and "95% CI" in the row "Patient Age"

[image: Table with SMDs for every variable]

I thought it would work like this, but it doesn't:

```
trial %>%
  select(age, grade, response, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    label = list(age ~ "Patient Age"),
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
    digits = list(age ~ c(0, 1))
  )%>%
  add_difference(list(!age~"smd", age ~ NULL))
```

Instead it used the default test for continuous variables:

[image: Table with additional test]

Comment: Use `add_difference(include=-age)`

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer. My interpretation of the documentation was wrong. I was wondering why the include statement could be repeated, since I wanted to include the variable to the overall output. Makes sense now!